# Android: developing some module in hydrid in native android app

Tags: android, cordova

I am integrating audio and video chat in my existing android app developed in native code(Java).There is a third party cordova plugin which integrates chat in android app. So is it possible to develop only the chat module using cordova and then integrate it in existing native app.

Comment: don't mix in cordova! You'll get a lot of trouble later on! Just google for chat-libraries, I believe there are plenty of them already. Like here https://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=android%20chat%20library&btnG=Google-Suche&meta=

Comment: i dont know much about cordova.But is it possible to integrate it that way..

Comment: no, at least it would be not as simple as you may think.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I would better go for link u suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's gonna be tricky to integrate Cordova in a native app.

May I ask you why you need it that way specifically?

There is a plenty providers who have audio and video chat implemented as native Android libraries. 
It seems to me that it would be more logical and easy to use a native Android library in your case.

You can try ConnectyCube, for example, since there are both text chat and audio/video chat for Android. So, you can have it all from one provider.